# Select para saber os clientes sem atendimento nos ultimos 30 dias plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Tenho as seguintes colunas: 
CODCLI, CLIENTE E DTULTCOMP
Preciso saber os clientes que não compraram nos últimos 30 dias.
a Coluna DTULTCOMP está no formato DATE 
Tabela: PCLIENT

Comment: Essas colunas estão em qual(is) tabela(s)?

Comment: Que base de dados estás a usar? MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL? Já experimentaste algo? Presumo que se sim, e que o teu problema está na condição `WHERE`, que precisas que seja a `DTULTCOMP < (AGORA - 30 dias)`, é isso?

Comment: Base de dados Oracle.

Comment: Isso mesmo, deu certo obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se a precisão é por mês pode utilizar a função [Add_Mouth](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603), passando um valor negativo, retirando meses da data, ex:

```
select * from SuaTabela 
 where SuaColuna < add_months(sysdate, -1)
```

Se a operação necessita ser em dias basta fazer uma subtração na data de comparação, ex:

```
select * from SuaTabela 
 where SuaColuna < sysdate - 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tabela
where DTULTCOMP is null
or DTULTCOMP < (SYSDATE - 30)
```

Caso queira saber apenas os que efetivamente compraram algo, até porque porque haver clientes que compraram a muito tempo atrás, ou simplesmente nunca compraram, retire a condicao que testa nulo.

```
Select * from tabela
where DTULTCOMP < (SYSDATE - 30)
```

Comment: DEU CERTO, valeu.